# Prestashop Admin panel Menu's Not visible

Tags: prestashop

I am completely new to prestashop and managing a already developed website. When i login to the admin panel of my website I can only see five menus in the panel. I wanted to know how can i enable other menus which are available after a fresh installation of prestashop. I have attached the image for reference. Thanks in advance.[Menu's that i can see in my admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llw2O.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have an administrator account but an Employee one with restrictions.